# How to convert certain lines from an XML file into a csv

Tags: python, xml, parsing, data-conversion

I am currently trying to convert a few thousand xml files into csv so I can do some easier data work. I am trying to convert just one of these first just so I can make sure that it works and then I can loop it.

I have been able to get most of it figured out, as I found a nifty tutorial online. My XML file looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orbit id="14737">
    <frame>
        <time>2015-08-15T05:28:39.014</time>
        <sza>113.48 deg</sza>
        <alt>1552 km</alt>
        <lat>-66.96 deg</lat>
        <lon>196.11 deg</lon>
        <x>-0.58 Rm</x>
        <rho>1.33 Rm</rho>
        <hperiod>0</hperiod>
        <hperiodquality>0</hperiodquality>
        <vperiod delaytime="167.443 μs">0</vperiod>
        <vperiodquality>0</vperiodquality>
        <cutoff>0</cutoff>
        <ionospheretrace delaytime="167.443 μs"/>
        <maxfreqquality>0</maxfreqquality>
        <groundtrace delaytime="167.443 μs"/>
    </frame>
...
```

This continues, of course.

My issue arises with lines such as the ionospheretrace delaytime, where this does not follow the general formating for the XML file.

My phython code looks as follows:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("14737.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# open a file for writing

Orbit_data = open('/csv/14737', 'w')

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(Orbit_data)
orbit_head = []

orbit_head.append('time')            
orbit_head.append('sza')
orbit_head.append('alt')
orbit_head.append('lat')
orbit_head.append('lon')
orbit_head.append('x')
orbit_head.append('rho')
orbit_head.append('hperiod')
orbit_head.append('hperiodquality')
orbit_head.append('vperiod')
orbit_head.append('vperiodquality')
orbit_head.append('cutoff')
orbit_head.append('ionospheretrace delaytime')
orbit_head.append('maxfreqquality')
orbit_head.append('groundtrace delatytime')

csvwriter.writerow(orbit_head)


for member in root.findall('frame'):
    frame = []
    address_list = []

    time = member.find('time').text
    frame.append(time)
    sza = member.find('sza').text
    resident.append(sza)
    alt = member.find('alt').text
    resident.append(alt)

    lat = member.find('lat').text
        frame.append(lat)
        lon = member.find('lon').text
        frame.append(lon)
        x = member.find('x').text
        frame.append(x)
        rho = member.find('rho').text
        frame.append(rho)
        hperiod = member.find('hperiod').text
        frame.append(hperiod)
        hperiodquality = member.find('hperiodquality').text
        frame.append(hperiodquality)

        vperiod = member.find('vperiod').text
        frame.append(vperiod)
        vperiodquality = member.find('vperiodquality').text
        frame.append(vperiodquality)
        cutoff = member.find('cutoff').text
        frame.append(cutoff)
        ionospheretrace_delaytime = member.find('ionopspheretrace delaytime').text
        frame.append(ionospheretrace_delaytime)
        maxfreqquality = member.find('maxfreqquality').text
        frame.append(maxfreqquality)
        groundtrace_delatytime = member.find('groundtrace delatytime').text
        frame.append(groundtrace_delatytime)



    csvwriter.writerow(frame)
Orbit_data.close()
```

What I hope to happen is that I can store the delaytime somehow, but I am not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: *"hope to ... store the delaytime"*: Use `vperiod.attrib['delaytime']`. Read [xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a generic approach for collecting the data.

The idea is to mark the 'special' tags (those that we need to use the attribute value)

I skip the csv generation because your main challenge was how to extract the data from the xml.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ATTRIBUTE_BASED_ELEMENTS = ['ionospheretrace', 'vperiod', 'groundtrace']

tree = ET.parse('56116141.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

data = []

for frame in root.findall('.//frame'):
    one_frame = []
    for child in list(frame):
        if child.tag in ATTRIBUTE_BASED_ELEMENTS:
            one_frame.append(child.attrib['delaytime'])
        else:
            one_frame.append(child.text)
    data.append(one_frame)

for frame in data:
    print(frame)
```

56116141.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orbit id="14737">
    <frame>
        <time>2015-08-15T05:28:39.014</time>
        <sza>113.48 deg</sza>
        <alt>1552 km</alt>
        <lat>-66.96 deg</lat>
        <lon>196.11 deg</lon>
        <x>-0.58 Rm</x>
        <rho>1.33 Rm</rho>
        <hperiod>0</hperiod>
        <hperiodquality>0</hperiodquality>
        <vperiod delaytime="167.443 μs">0</vperiod>
        <vperiodquality>0</vperiodquality>
        <cutoff>0</cutoff>
        <ionospheretrace delaytime="167.443 μs"/>
        <maxfreqquality>0</maxfreqquality>
        <groundtrace delaytime="167.443 μs"/>
    </frame>
    <frame>
        <time>2016-08-15T05:28:39.014</time>
        <sza>113.42 deg</sza>
        <alt>1553 km</alt>
        <lat>-66.16 deg</lat>
        <lon>196.41 deg</lon>
        <x>-0.56 Rm</x>
        <rho>1.39 Rm</rho>
        <hperiod>1</hperiod>
        <hperiodquality>1</hperiodquality>
        <vperiod delaytime="107.443 μs">0</vperiod>
        <vperiodquality>1</vperiodquality>
        <cutoff>1</cutoff>
        <ionospheretrace delaytime="167.343 μs"/>
        <maxfreqquality>1</maxfreqquality>
        <groundtrace delaytime="967.443 μs"/>
    </frame>
</orbit>
```

output

```
['2015-08-15T05:28:39.014', '113.48 deg', '1552 km', '-66.96 deg', '196.11 deg', '-0.58 Rm', '1.33 Rm', '0', '0', '167.443 μs', '0', '0', '167.443 μs', '0', '167.443 μs']
['2016-08-15T05:28:39.014', '113.42 deg', '1553 km', '-66.16 deg', '196.41 deg', '-0.56 Rm', '1.39 Rm', '1', '1', '107.443 μs', '1', '1', '167.343 μs', '1', '967.443 μs']
```